# Parse json string with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have this json string:

```
{"work_completion_forms": 
     [
         {
             "id": "2a6aae87-af4f-4aa9-8e43-05af2be6d963",  
             "name": "File"
         }, 
         { 
             "id": "b6e35c72-026e-4ef0-8eff-36d040054a93",
             "name": "Comment"
         }
     ]
}
```

How i can parse it?

I try this:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
Parse p = g.fromJson(result, Parse.class);
String[] s = p.get_work_completion_forms();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length;i++){
    Log.d(s[i], "lol");
}

public class Parse {

    public String[] work_completion_forms;

    public String[] get_work_completion_forms()
    {
       return work_completion_forms;
    }

}
```

Comment: whats the issue in ur code

Comment: kindly post the code and if any error post ur logcat

Comment: use this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ this will surely helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] work_completion_forms
```

This is the issue with your code. They type of `work_completion_forms` is not `String`, rather something more complex. Try like that

```
public class WorKCompletionForms {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    // getters and setters
}

WokCompletionForms[] s = p.get_work_completion_forms();
for (int i = 0; i < s.length;i++){
    Log.d("TAG", s[i].getId());
}
```